# Getting all calendar events in moodle using Web Services API

Tags: web-services, calendar, moodle

after the upgrade of my moodle to 2.5dev version I'm trying to get calendar events using **core_calendar_get_calendar_events** function in url:

```
http://localhost/moodle-2.5dev/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=token_here&wsfunction=core_calendar_get_calendar_events
```

The result is just an empty xml file with the elements `KEY name="events"` and `KEY name="warnings"`. From Documents API I got that it needs to required parameter **events**, but have no idea how to use it, since the function is new itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be looking in ROOT/calendar/externallib.php - which might be more accurately called the component's web service library. Look for the function `get_calendar_events_parameters`: This tells you that the function expects two arguments. The first argument, 'events', is an array with 'eventids' containing an array of ids; likewise 'courseids' and 'groupids'.

The second argument is 'options' which is an array containing 'userevents' (bool), 'siteevents' (bool), 'timestart' (int), 'timeend' (int) & 'ignorehidden' (bool).

So the function call should be something like:

```
$soap->core_calendar_get_calendar_events(array(array(1),array(2),array(3)), array(true, true, 0, 0, true));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm looking to call for the `core_calendar_get_calendar_events` by URL (like with the url mentioned above). could you please explain your solution in form of url? i'm new in using moodle web services. thanks